# Differentiate $2\pi x \cos(\pi x^2)$

Tags: calculus

Can someone please explain to me how to differentiate this equation?

$$2\pi x \cos(\pi x^2)$$

I know you use the chain rule and the product rule but I cannot get the final answer correct.

$$(2 \pi) [-\sin(\pi x^2) 2\pi*x]$$

$$=-4 \pi^2*x* \sin(\pi x^2)$$

Comment: Show the work you've done so far and we can help you find your mistake.

Comment: I edited initial to show my work

Comment: I think you forgot an $x$ somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot an $x$ somewhere. If we use the chain rule,
$$f'(x)=(2 \pi x)(-2 \pi x\sin(\pi x^2))$$
which becomes
$$f'(x)=-4\pi ^2x^2\sin(\pi x^2)$$
not
$$f'(x)=(2\pi)(-2 \pi x\sin(\pi x^2)$$
becoming
$$f'(x)=-4\pi ^2 x \sin(\pi x^2)$$

Comment: Note: my answer is incomplete, because I only analyzed the part of the equation regarding $\sin(\pi x^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

So,
$\frac{d}{dx}[2\pi x \cos(\pi x^2)]$

The first step I like to do is to pull out constants since $(\alpha f)' = \alpha (f')$

$=2\pi\frac{d}{dx}[x \cos(\pi x^2)]$

Then is product rule with $f=x$ and $g= \cos(\pi x^2)$, you have $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$

$=2\pi(1\cdot\cos(\pi x^2) + x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}[\cos(\pi x^2)])$

Now for the final piece, apply chain rule where $g=\pi x^2$ and $f = \cos(x)$ which states that $[f(g)]' = f'(g)\cdot g'$

$=2\pi(\cos(\pi x^2) + x\cdot (-\sin(\pi x^2))\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[\pi x^2])$

one more derivative to take...

$=2\pi(\cos(\pi x^2) + x\cdot (-\sin(\pi x^2))\cdot(2\pi x))$

finally algebra to simply things

$=2\pi\cos (\pi x^2) - 4\pi^2 x^2\sin(\pi x^2)$

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you have to use, first, the product rule and, second, the chain rule.

This gives:

$$\frac{d}{dx} 2 \pi x \cos(\pi x^2)=2 \pi \frac{d}{dx}  (x \cdot \cos(\pi x^2)) = 2 \pi \left[ \left( \frac{d}{dx} x \right) \cdot \cos(\pi x^2) + x \left( \frac{d}{dx} \cos(\pi x^2) \right) \right]=2 \pi \left[ \cos(\pi x^2)+x \left(-\sin(\pi x^2)\cdot \frac{d}{dx} (\pi x^2)\right) \right]=2 \pi \left[ \cos(\pi x^2)+x \left(-\sin(\pi x^2) \cdot  (2 \pi x)\right) \right]$$